# skip pre-push husky for git tag?

Tags: node.js, bash, git, npm

I have a pre-push file

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run build && git add dist && git commit --amend --no-edit --no-verify
```

the problem is this will run `git push origin tag myTag`, how to avoid this? I know I add `--no-verify` but it's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the pre-push file that is pushing the tags - it is your git push command. `--no-verify` doesn't do anything here, it only affects the pre-commit hook. I think you only believe `--no-verify` does something because you ran `git push` twice; on the second time, there were no tags to push that origin didn't already have.

To actually fix this, use the `--[no-]follow-tags` flag

```bash
git push --no-follow-tags
```

To make this setting permanent for your project, configure `push.default` to prevent the pushing of tags by default:

```bash
git config push.followTags false
```

Comment: I want to avoid pre-push hook that's why I use --no-verify. I actually need to push the tag.